# ember-data-tastypie-adapter not working

Tags: javascript, django, ember.js, tastypie

I'm planing to create an ember.js app that is served by my tastypie api soon and I'm trying to get into ember at the moment but i am stuck!

The ember application I created (like in the tutorial video with fixture data) works fine but now I am trying to switch from the fixtures to my API and this is where my problem starts:

this is the django model I want to display for this short test:

```
class New(models.Model):
date = models.DateField("Erstellt am", auto_created=True, auto_now_add=True)
title = models.CharField("Titel", max_length=250)
content = models.TextField("Inhalt")

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.title + ', ' + self.date.strftime('%d.%m.%Y')
```

this is my ModelResource:

```
class NewResource(ModelResource):
class Meta:
    queryset = New.objects.all()
    resource_name = 'new'
    always_return_data = True

def determine_format(self, request):
    return 'application/json'
```

this is what I get when I open `http://127.0.0.1:8000/v1/new/`:

```
{"meta": {"limit": 20, "next": null, "offset": 0, "previous": null, "total_count": 2}, "objects": [{"content": "Lorem Ipsum Dolorem", "date": "2013-09-27", "id": 1, "resource_uri": "/app/new/1/", "title": "Test"}, {"content": "Lorem Ipsum Dolorem", "date": "2013-09-27", "id": 2, "resource_uri": "/app/new/2/", "title": "This is a test title"}]}
```

this is my app.js file :

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('news');
});

App.store = DS.Store.create({
    revision: 7,
    adapter: DS.DjangoTastypieadapter.extend({
        serverDomain: "http://127.0.0.1:8000",
        namespace: "v1"
    })
});

App.New = DS.Model.extend({
    date: DS.attr('string'),
    title: DS.attr('string'),
    content: DS.attr('string'),
});

App.NewsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        var news = App.New.find()
        return news;
    }
});
```

this is my handlebar:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="news">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2">
            {{#each}}
                {{#link-to 'new' this}} 
                    {{title}} // {{date}} 
                {{/link-to}}
                <hr>
            {{/each}}
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            {{outlet}}
        </div>
    </div>
```

as I said the fixture data has the same form as the JSON objects I get from the API but there is no content displayed when I do it like this. (I've got the ember-data-tastypie-adapter files included in my index.html)  Can someone help me?

Comment: I believe you have encountered the same problem I had - JSON (Django) is served from different origin (hostname+port) than Ember app.
I proxied API requests, so origin stays the sames. One could, probably, try to change Access-Control-Allow-Origin header, see if that works.

Comment: thanks for the response! But i guess i gave up on that one..